# Integrating a surface in a cylinder

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Consider 
$$\Phi: \mathbb{R}^2\to   \mathbb{R}^3,~ \Phi(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}u+v\\u-v\\2uv\end{pmatrix}$$
I want to find the volume of the area $\Phi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ inside the cylinder $C:x^2+y^2<4$.

First I found the Jacobi-matrix of $\Phi$
$$J(u,v)_\Phi=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&-1\\ 2v&2u\end{pmatrix},~J(u,v)_\Phi^T=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}& 1v\\ \frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&1u\end{pmatrix}$$
So the Metric-Tensor and its determinant are
$$\mathscr{G}(\Phi)=J(u,v)_\Phi^T\cdot J(u,v)_\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+2v^2}{2}&vu\\ vu&\frac{1+2u^2}{2}\end{pmatrix},\quad \mathscr{g}(\Phi)=\frac{2v^2+2u^2+1}{4}$$

But Im not sure how to find the   volume;

Comment: Isn´t $J\Phi|_{(u,v)}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\\2v&2u\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathcal{g}(\Phi)=\frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2)+\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Yes it is, I messed up, fixed it

Comment: I htink in this case, your volume element would be $\sqrt{|\det{g}|} du \wedge dv$

Comment: Not sure what $du \wedge dv$ means

Comment: Suggestion: Convert the inequality $x^2+y^2<4$ into an inequality on $u$ and $v$ and then you'll know over what region to integrate. By the way, you mean *area*, not *volume*.